# AudioToolbox MusicPlayer change program has no effect

Tags: ios, midi, audiotoolbox

MIDI noob in training here...
I have been using MusicPlayer/MusicSequence/MusicTrack to play MIDI notes on devices running iOS.  The notes are playing fine.  I am struggling to change the instrument being played.  As far as I can figure this is how to do it:

```
-(void) setInstrument:(MIDIInstruments) program channel:(int) channel MusicTrack:(MusicTrack*) track time:(float) time {
    if(channel < 0 || channel > 15 || program >=MIDI_INSTRUMENT_COUNT || time < 0) {
        return;
    }

    MIDIChannelMessage programChange = { ((UInt8)0xC) << 4 | ((UInt8)channel), ((UInt8)program), 0, 0};

    OSStatus result = MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(*track, time, &programChange);
    if(result != noErr) {
        [NSException raise:@"Set Instrument" format:@"Failed to set instrument error: %@", [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:result userInfo:nil]];
    }
}
```

In this case channel is 0 or 1, I tried several instruments through out the range of valid instrument enumerations, the time is 0.0, and the MusicTrack is valid, and has ~30 seconds of note events.  The call to set the channel event passes back noErr.  I am stumped...Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had read in other posts that I would be able to generate midi using Music Player and friends.  It provides for program changes.  So, I had figured it was supported.  After exhausting all theories, I turned to `AUGraph`.  I added a *.sf2 file that I found online, instantiated the `AUGraph`, two `AudioUnits`, a `MidiEndpointRef`, and a `MidiClientRef`; according to this [tutorial](http://www.deluge.co/?q=midi-driven-animation-core-audio-objective-c).

It was in the endpoint callback that I had to turn notes on and off using `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` on the `samplerUnit` that seemed to allow for the program change.  Whereas before I was just loading note events into a `MusicTrack` and playing/stoping the `MusicPlayer`.